# Partitioning SSD for multiple OS's

Tags: dd

I installed a SanDisk 240GB SSD. My old HDD will now be my storage. I've partitioned the SSD into 4 roughly 55GB partitions. I've also done a pvcreate, vgcreate, and an lvcreate for each partition named for the OS it will house. I have the .iso files saved to my HDD Downloads folder.

Do I need to make a file system on each partition now before I install the OS? Or do I simply `dd if=...`, etc? I tried the DD route, but my boot menu only shows the SSD as a whole.
Not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

Normally each OS installation should be able to create the file systems it needs. Just point the installation to the according partition to use.

(Where I am not really sure if all OS installation media will come with the according software to support LVM during install.)

Comment: So, for example, I should do: dd if=/path/centos.iso of=/dev/sdb1? Then, when I reboot and F8 into the boot setup I should see this separate option?

Comment: No, B. Tague, copying the iso to a partition will not install the OS. You need to run the installer by booting the livecd or USB disk containing the iso. Then, from within the installer choose the appropriate logical volumes. If the installer does not support LVM, you'll need to use the partition. As for the boot menu, it depends on whether the PC uses a BIOS or UEFI to boot.

Comment: Thank you Jaleks and thank you Emmanuel. I was hoping to do it via command line so I can practice. Is there a set of commands to install an OS from .iso image on a partitioned SSD from a saved on a separate hard drive?

Comment: There is no general 'yes' to this question, as under some circumstances you might be able to run the installer off the .iso, which you would first have to mount (with option `loop`), but as most scenarios will not be designed for this approach, you might have problems during the installation. And of course there is no general HowTo for doing this.

Comment: You jogged my memory. I do recall working with the loop function. I will reply back here with the results and steps if I am successful. Thanks!